# Azure Mobile Services Starter Issues - Database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to create a simple backend for a html/JavaScript app. I started off by creating a new visual Studio Project using the azure mobile Service template. I created a simple DataObject class called 'ProjectItem' which is looking like this:

```
   public class ProjectItem : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.EntityData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

After that I added a table Controller and there was no need to touch any Code in that class.
In the web api config I added this peace of Code:

```
List<ProjectItem> projectItems = new List<ProjectItem>
        {
            new ProjectItem {Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Title = "First Project", Description = "My First Project Description" },
            new ProjectItem {Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Title = "Second Project", Description = "My Second Project Description" }
        };
        foreach (ProjectItem projectItem in projectItems)
        {
            context.Set<ProjectItem>().Add(projectItem);
        }
```

I debugged the Service on my localhost and it was working just fine.
Now I wanted to host it on azure and there the Problems started for me. 
Here the stepps I did using azure:

1. I created an empty database on the new Portal
2. In visual Studio I clicked publish (my solution) and created a new mobile Service selecting the empty database - I didn't touch the rest of the Settings. The mobile Service is now "up and running".

I only have worked with sqlite since now so I opened the database in visual Studio and wanted to look at the test items I created (the 2 Project Items).

**But there is no ProjectItem table and no ToDoItem table either!**

[image: Database in vs]

- How can this happen?
- What did I do wrong?
- Why is it creating the tables running on localhost but when
  Publishing on azure it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it is not that simple as to create the object model and it will create the same table in the backend (SQL Azure to be clear, or Azure Storage). You need to create it using Azure dashboard, or do the custom API and do as [described here](http://yuluer.com/page/dgfadefc-azure-mobile-app-android-programmatically-create-easy-table.shtml). You may do the same in the Visual Studio, i think, or from the SQL Server Management Studio connected to the SQL Azure db.

For Mobile Services, however, if you set the dynamic schema on the dashboard, it will be able to create new columns when they are in the object, but it is not recommended in the production.

So, you did not anything wrong, it looks that the creation of the table programmatically is just not a supported way (only by dashboard or any type of the explorer like SSMS or VS). Anyway (by the way), they will be not in the System Tables branch.

Comment: May we chat a little?

Comment: And your link is for mobile apps not for mobile Services which are different Things.